# handling views on click button in vaadin

Tags: java, spring, maven, vaadin, vaadin7

Am very very new to Vaadin. Am setting up the project by looking into Github and other docs, where am using Spring-security, Vaadin, Maven.

I created sample vaadin-maven with spring security project. Now am getting login page then after suucessful login, am getting some `MainView.java`.

Am trying to change the view `onclick` button. But am not able to get that. Please suggest me how can i go to another view on clicking the button in Vaadin.

Below is the code:

**MyUI.java**

```
@Component
@Theme("mytheme")
@Scope("prototype")
@Widgetset("com.mygubbi.GameProject.MyAppWidgetset")
public class MyUI extends UI implements ErrorHandler {
    @Override
    protected void init(final VaadinRequest request) {
        VaadinSession.getCurrent().setErrorHandler(this);
        setSizeFull();
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);

        DiscoveryNavigator navigator = new DiscoveryNavigator(this, this);
    }

    /**
     * Exception on action
     */
    @Override
    public void error(com.vaadin.server.ErrorEvent event) {
        // connector event
        if (event.getThrowable().getCause() instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
            AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException = (AccessDeniedException) event.getThrowable().getCause();
            Notification.show(accessDeniedException.getMessage(), Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            // Cleanup view. Now Vaadin ignores errors and always shows the 
            //view.  :-(
            // since beta10
            setContent(null);
            return;
        }

        // Error on page load. Now it doesn't work. User sees standard error 
        //page.
        if (event.getThrowable() instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
            AccessDeniedException exception = (AccessDeniedException) event.getThrowable();

            Label label = new Label(exception.getMessage());
            label.setWidth(-1, Unit.PERCENTAGE);

            Link goToMain = new Link("Go to main", new ExternalResource("/"));

            VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
            layout.addComponent(label);
            layout.addComponent(goToMain);
            layout.setComponentAlignment(label, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
            layout.setComponentAlignment(goToMain, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);

            VerticalLayout mainLayout = new VerticalLayout();
            mainLayout.setSizeFull();
            mainLayout.addComponent(layout);
            mainLayout.setComponentAlignment(layout, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);

            setContent(mainLayout);
            Notification.show(exception.getMessage(), Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

        DefaultErrorHandler.doDefault(event);
    }
}
```

---

**MainView.java**

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@VaadinView(MainView.NAME)
public class MainView extends Panel implements View {
    public static final String NAME = "";

    private Label usernameLabel = new Label();
    private Label rolesLabel = new Label();

    @PostConstruct
    public void PostConstruct() {
        setSizeFull();
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setSpacing(true);
        layout.setMargin(true);

        HorizontalLayout usernameLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
        usernameLayout.setSpacing(true);
        usernameLayout.addComponent(new Label("Username:"));
        usernameLayout.addComponent(usernameLabel);

        HorizontalLayout userRolesLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
        userRolesLayout.setSpacing(true);
        userRolesLayout.addComponent(new Label("Roles:"));
        userRolesLayout.addComponent(rolesLabel);

        layout.addComponent(usernameLayout);
        layout.addComponent(userRolesLayout);

        Link userView = new Link("ROLE_USER View (disabled, if user doesn't have access) ", new ExternalResource("#!" + RoleUserView.NAME));
        Link roleView = new Link("ROLE_ADMIN View (disabled, if user doesn'thave access) ", new ExternalResource("#!" + RoleAdminView.NAME));

        userView.setEnabled(SpringSecurityHelper.hasRole("ROLE_USER"));
        roleView.setEnabled(SpringSecurityHelper.hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN"));

        layout.addComponent(userView);
        layout.addComponent(roleView);
        layout.addComponent(new Link("ROLE_ADMIN View (throw exception, if user doesn 't have access)", new ExternalResource("#!" + RoleAdminView.NAME)));

        layout.addComponent(new Link("Logout", new ExternalResource("/j_spring_security_logout")));

        Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                layout.addComponent(new Label("Thank you for clicking"));
            }
        });

        layout.addComponent(button);
        setContent(layout);
    }


    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
        User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : user.getAuthorities()) {
            roles.add(grantedAuthority.getAuthority());
        }

        usernameLabel.setValue(user.getUsername());
        rolesLabel.setValue(StringUtils.join(roles, ","));
    }


}
```

---

Please suggest me how can i use two buttons here. If i click Button one it should goto `oneView.java` and if i click on button2 it should goto `twoView.java`

A million tons of thanks in advance. :) hoping a good response from my stackoverflow guru's. :)

Comment: First of all, if you're using spring boot, there is [a nice tutorial on spring boot & vaadin](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Spring+Vaadin/I+-+Getting+Started+with+Vaadin+Spring+and+Spring+Boot) which also includes a chapter on navigation (you read it even if you're not using boot because the concepts are similar). Otherwise the Vaadin book has [a good explanation as well on the navigation feature] which neds minor adjusments for spring (https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-navigator.html). Second, where are you calling the `createNavigationButton` method in your code...

Comment: Thank for the response. Am not using Spring Boot. I didn't understood how to navigate the view on click button. Sorry, i tried that createNavigationButton. Am deleting that method now. you can see the updated code. And about the doc, i had read that before writing my issue here. :(

Comment: Usually you have to get a hold of the navigator instance and _tell it_ to go to another view, something along the lines of `getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo("viewName");`. If you've already tried this, what trouble did you have? **P.S.** you can use @username when replying to someone's comment so they get notified ;-)

Comment: @Morfic When am using button.addClickListener(event -->  getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(viewName));  showing the error "event cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: The lambda [_arrow token_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax) has only 1 minus sign in it. It should read `->` instead of `-->`, and also make sure you're using JDK 8.